# loop data in datalist

Tags: vb.net, loops, datalist

How do i loop through each data in the datalist? Because i am currently getting one value from "Label8" which causes my "Label7" to show "No" for all.

```
 Protected Sub DataList2_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItemEventArgs) Handles DataList2.ItemDataBound
    For Each li As DataListItem In DataList2.Items
        Dim labelasd As Label = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("**Label8**"), Label)
        Dim reviewid As Integer = labelasd.Text
        Dim connectionString As String = _
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()
        Dim sql As String = "Select Count(reviewYes) AS Expr1 From ProductReviewHelp Where ProductReviewID = " & reviewid & ""
        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        Dim countofreview As Integer = 0
        Dim reviewcountboolean As Boolean
        If (reader.Read()) Then
            If (IsDBNull(reader.GetValue(0)) = False) Then


                countofreview = reader.GetValue(0)


            End If
        End If
        If countofreview = 0 Then
            reviewcountboolean = False
        Else
            reviewcountboolean = True
        End If

        If (reviewcountboolean = True) Then

            Dim label1 As Label = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl(**"Label7"**), Label)
            label1.Text = "Hello"

        ElseIf (reviewcountboolean = False) Then

            Dim label1 As Label = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl(**"Label7"**), Label)
            label1.Text = "No"

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

How do i loop through each data in the datalist? Because i am currently getting one value from "Label8" which causes my "Label7" to show "No" for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping on your DataList2 items but, at every loop, you update the label7 with the logic of the current item, effectively removing the result of the previous loop. This means that, when you reach the last item, the Label7 will reflect the string "Hello" or "No" depending on the logic applied to the last item in your loop.

Apart from this logical error, you have also numerous errors in the code shown.

- The connection is never closed.
- You use string concatenation instead of parameters.
- You use ExecuteReader when in this case an ExecuteScalar is better
  suited.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through then using a loop here is an example

```
Try
        readFromDL1 = DirectCast(SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
        readFromQ = DirectCast(SqlDataSource7.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    'End 
    'datalist1
    i = 0
    _rowCount = DataList1.Items.Count
    If _rowCount > 0 Then
        _getCall = DataList1.Items.Item(i).FindControl("lnkEdit")
    End If

    For Each readr As DataRowView In readFromQ
        findQNumber = readr(1).ToString()
        For Each readfdlr1 As DataRowView In readFromDL1
            findQNumber1 = readfdlr1(1).ToString

            Try
                indexofitems = DataList1.Items.Item(i1).ItemIndex
                If findQNumber.ToString = findQNumber1.ToString Then
                    _getCall = DataList1.Items.Item(indexofitems).FindControl("lnkEdit")
                    _getCall.Text = "Called"
                    _getCall.Enabled = False
                    _getCall.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
                    _getCall.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow

                End If
                i1 = i1 + 1
            Catch e As Exception

            End Try

        Next
        i1 = 0
        i = i + 1
```